# convert string date to sql date format

Tags: java, sql, string, date, date-formatting

I want to convert this string "2022-01-13 14:33:07.996" to java sql date. I have read the answers and I have converted the string to java util date and then to java sql date. I just don't know how to get the full date in java sql date format

```
String dateStart = "2022-01-13 14:33:07.996";
         DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
         Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(dateStart);
         java.util.Date utilDate = date1;
         java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date1.getTime());
System.out.println(sqlDate);
```

in out put i get this

```
2022-01-13
```

but I want something like this `2022-01-13 14:33:07.996` in java sql date format

Comment: "SQL Date values do not have a time component" is mentioned 6 times in the official javadoc of that class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html - That's why your first source for debugging should always be to look at the official documentation!

Comment: I don't think you should be using a `java.sql.Date` if you want a class that can store information about *something like this `2022-01-13 14:33:07.996`*. A `java.sql.Date` simply has year, month of year and day of month as its attributes, nothing more, no time of day, no hours, minutes, seconds or smaller (if you don't believe it, read [a document that contains a remarkable set of the words *deprecated* and *deprecation*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html)). You'll be best adviced using one of the solutions provided by @BasilBorque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

To write date-time values to a database, use appropriate objects, not text. For a date-only value, use `LocalDate`.

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(
    … ,
    LocalDateTime
    .parse( "2022-01-13 14:33:07.996".replace( " " , "T" ) )
    .toLocalDate()
)
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

## Date-only

You said:

> 2022-01-13 14:33:07.996 in java sql date format

That is a contradiction. A `java.sql.Date` object represents a date-only, not a date with time-of-day.

## `java.time.LocalDateTime`

Parse your input string as a `LocalDateTime` because it lacks any indicator of time zone or offset. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
String input = "2022-01-13 14:33:07.996".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## `java.time.LocalDate`

Extract the date portion.

```
LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
```

## Database access

Write to database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieve from database.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

These matters have been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.